# Can a Black hole only have negative EM charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, electrons, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I understand that Black holes can have EM charge, they can have EM fields around them.

But is that possible that a black hole has more positrons and protons inside it (or that these have more EM charge), then electrons (have EM charge)?

Will in this case the black hole still have a negative EM charge or not?

Question:

1. Can a black hole only have negative EM charge or can it have the opposite too?

Comment: Yes, black holes can have charge, and charge can be negative.

Comment: @knzhou my question is the opposite charge, can that be too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Reissner–Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) for a non-rotating charged black hole [and more generally the [Kerr-Newman metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) for a rotating charged black hole] only depends on $Q^2$, i.e. the sign of the electric charge $Q$ does not matter for the construction (except of course for the direction of the $E$-field).